# Summernote - Como exibir tela cheia fora do modal?

Tags: bootstrap-3, summernote

Eu uso desse plugin: https://summernote.org/

Segue código em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9rnj8rdo/

Quando eu clico "tela cheia", ela fica com tela cheia dentro do modal. Quero que ele fique com tela cheia fora do modal. Alguma solução ?